# Another (LEFT) JOIN question (now with CASE inside ON)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a change in a legacy 370 lines long SQL. My problem narrows to:

```
SELECT ... FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T2.COL1 = (CASE WHEN T1.COL5 = 5 THEN 1
                                                  WHEN T3.COL2 = 16 THEN 7
                                                  ELSE -1 END)
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.COL3 = T2.COL3
```

I got the error that "T3.COL2" is not defined. The problem is that I cannot use T3 inside "CASE WHEN" because it is defined after/below CASE. I cannot move it above "LEFT JOIN T2" because T3 references T2. How to fix it?

DB is Oracle 19.

What I added into the existing SQL is line: "WHEN T3.COL2 = 16 THEN 7". Other code is legacy SQL code.

Comment: Move the JOIN between T2 and T3 in a subquery, returns the required info to later join it with T1.

Comment: @p3consulting can you show me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets to set the precedence of the joins:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM   T1
       LEFT JOIN (
          T2
          LEFT JOIN T3
          ON T3.COL3 = T2.COL3
       )
       ON T1.ID = T2.ID
          AND T2.COL1 = CASE
                        WHEN T1.COL5 = 5
                        THEN 1
                        WHEN T3.COL2 = 16
                        THEN 7
                        ELSE -1
                        END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and see if it works? I haven't made a `JOIN` like this before, but maybe if you declare the tables first and then the conditions it will work.

```
SELECT ... FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 
    LEFT JOIN T3 
ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T2.COL1 = (CASE WHEN T1.COL5 = 5 THEN 1
                                     WHEN T3.COL2 = 16 THEN 7
                                ELSE -1 END)
ON T3.COL3 = T2.COL3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seems to be allowed with Oracle DB: "ON" must be specified right after its LEFT JOIN. Maybe with some other DBs this would work...